# What for do we use CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION in PHP's cURL?

Tags: php, curl

Could you describe it in examples, please?

Answer (score 12):

I know this is an old question, but maybe my answer will be of some help for you or someone else. The WRITEFUNCTION is useful for processing text as it comes streaming in or for aborting the download based on some condition. Here's an example that simply puts all the text into uppercase letters:

```
function get_html($url){
    $ch = curl_init();
    $obj = $this;//create an object variable to access class functions and variables
    $this->result = '';
    $callback = function ($ch, $str) use ($obj) {
        $obj->result .= strtoupper($str);
        return strlen($str);//return the exact length
    };
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, $callback);
    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $this->result;
}
```

To see how I used it, check out this link: [Parallel cURL Request with WRITEFUNCTION Callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15906261/parallel-curl-request-with-writefunction-callback/15958698#15958698).

Answer (score 1):

It is used with `curl_setopt` function.

`CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION` is the name of a callback function where the callback function takes two parameters. The first is the cURL resource, and the second is a string with the data to be written. The data must be written by using this callback function. Must return the exact number of bytes written or this will fail.

Comment: What does this mean: "Must return the exact number of bytes written or this will fail"?

Comment: How's that? What is the exact number of bytes written?

Comment: see this for an example of that answer: http://download1.parallels.com/Plesk/Expand/2.1.0-Release1/doc/expand-integrate-guide/17009.htm

Comment: And what for does it have to return the exact bytes? What's useful about it?

Comment: i think you should have a look at the example usage link i posted in my prevoius comments to get more idea about it and there are furnther explanations at the bottom of that page, Thanks

Comment: Thanks. I saw. But what's useful about it?

Comment: If you want the download to keep going you make the return value equal to the length of data that was provided.  If you want the download to abort you return a lesser value, or -1.  This tells curl you were unable to continue the download which curl will treat like a failure on the part of your handler to keep receiving data.  But if that's what you wanted to happen, that's fine.  You can still do something with the data you downloaded already.